как получить выбранные данные из автоматически созадной строки в datagrid wpf?
Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема с извлечением данных из автоматически созданной строки в datagrid. Пока эта строка не будет добавлена в datagrid(например, нажатием Enter или выделением другой строки), я не могу получить из неё данные, а мне надо получить данные до добавления строки( в datagrid). Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией и сможет подсказать, как все-таки получить данные из строки до добавления в DataGrid?
вот пример таблицы:
<DataGrid x:Name ="dataGrid2" ItemsSource="{Binding D2vm}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,106">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="S1" Binding="{Binding Pokaznuk}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="S2" Binding="{Binding NameGroup}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="S3" Binding="{Binding NumberGroup}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Save" Click="ShowHideDetails2" Background="Red" 
                        Visibility="{Binding IsFromDatabase, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Inverse}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>


Что значит "Автоматически созданная строка"? Я вижу привязку к D2vm, ну и если вам надо делать что-то ДО добавления в DataGrid, то делайте это ДО добавления в D2vm... Думайте про данные, а не про UI. И да, у вас нарушение MVVM, например, Click - означает то, что вы напрямую работаете с UI элементами из C# кода, а это нарушение.

Вы про строку что CanUserAddRows=true?

@vitidev да, про ту самую строку

@EvgeniyZ мне как раз таки нужно что-то сделать после добавления в DataGrid, а не до. Признаю, что нарушил MVVM, так как начал использовать его недавно, и просто нет времени доделать программу нормально.

"нет времени" - вот этого вот не надо, самая ужасная отмаза... "что-то сделать после добавления в DataGrid" - используйте ObservableCollection или BindingList, подписывайтесь на его событие изменения и получайте нужные данные. Пример тут (яб наверно даже сказал, дубликат...).

Используйте ObservableCollection, после добавления строки в таблицу, данные сами попадут в коллекцию.

Нет тут никакого нарушения MVVM. Click не означает нарушения. Он означает что данное действие будет на стороне вида. Должно ли быть действие во вьюмодели или виде - спорный вопрос. И как раз размещение лишнего действия во вьюмодели и есть нарушение MVVM, а не наоборот

@vitidev Как думаете, что человек делает по клику кнопки, которая зовется Сохранить? Очевидно, работает с данными... За данные какой слой отвечает? А связующий слой между действиями пользователя в UI и Model слоем какой? Если вы считаете, что обработка данных в UI элементах (в данном случае скорей всего окно)/View слое - это правильно и не является нарушением, то тут не о чем дальше просто говорить... Клики уместны только если идем UI логика (и то не всегда), в остальных случаях - команды!

@aepot суть в том, что есть строка (создается автоматически в DataGrid), в которой находятся 3 ComboBox (данные берутся из 3-х колонок в базе данных, для каждого ComboBox есть отдельная колонка). после того как пользователь выбрал элемент из ComboBox1 (в базе данных колонка 1), в ComboBox2 должен появиться элемент, который привязан к элементу (из второй колонки в базе данных), который был выбран в ComboBox1. Но так как строка, в которой выбираются элементы, не находится в DataGrid, я не могу получить значение из базы данных (второй колонки), которое отобразится в ComboBox2.

@EvgeniyZ а я смотрю на название хендлера который ShowHideDetails2 и предполагаю что там сначала показывается какая то форма или детали, а потом уже это дело можно будет сохранить. А UI логика это вещь спорная - должна ли работа с буфером обмена быть во вьюмодели? Должен ли быть флаг IsExpanded для экспандера во вьюмодели? Должна ли вьюмодель открывать новое окно? Вы правы в том, что не тема для комментов. В остальном все спорно

@vitidev Не стоит тогда писать ничего, раз для вас это лишь "спорно", ибо это вредный совет для новичка. Мой опыт подсказывает что наличие x:Name и Click у новичка - это с огромной долью вероятности нарушение, где по клику обрабатываются данные, а в VM делается что-то по типу window.TextBox.Text = ...;. В данном случае я уверен, что идет нарушение. Касательно вопросов "буфер" - смотря что делается, если явно работа с API Windows, то это вообще Model. "флаг IsExpanded" - если это состояние объекта, а не просто View, да. "открывать" - не она, а отдельный сервис, который она вызовет.

@Bonse ну тогда как я выше написал, ObservableCollection, далее отключите добавление элементов через DataGrid и добавьте например кнопку, которая будет добавлять элемент в конец коллекции отдельно. В противном случае придется вмешаться в работу самой таблицы, например сделать юзерконтрол на её основе, но это непростая задача, если вы не знакому с привязками и тем, как работают DependencyProperty.

@EvgeniyZ Для меня это не спорно. Я не пытаюсь запихать все во вьюмодели. Просто раз вы не согласны с этим, значит это спорно (но не для меня или вас). OnClick может открыть мессаджбокс с подтверждением (и только потом уже дернет вьюмодель). Должна ли это делать вьюмодель через отдельный сервис...зависит. IsExpanded экспандера - как IsExpanded не должен быть во вьюмодели. Нет для вм никакого экспандера, да и экспандера может не быть в другой реализации гуи. А вызов DialogService в принципе нарушает MVVM по своей природе

@vitidev Вас не туда занесло. В любом случае, ваш совет вреден для любого новичка, ибо новичок - это губка, которая впитывает все, что ему говорят, а если он раз увидит, что "Click это не нарушение" без какого либо объяснения почему, он будет везде использовать Click, а не команды. Осторожней пожалуйста со своими высказываниями.

Судя по комментариям вам нужно при создание объекта для DataGrid подгружать данные. Для этого вы можете подписаться на событие CollectionChanged у  ObservableCollection и сделать нужную обработку.
// Создание ObservableCollection
ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

// Подписка на событие CollectionChanged
myCollection.CollectionChanged += MyCollection_CollectionChanged;

// Метод-обработчик события CollectionChanged
private void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
        {
           //Какая то обработка
        }
    }
}

Полезные ссылки для чтивы:
https://www.gangofcoders.net/solution/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes/
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.13.php
https://www.itcodar.com/csharp/implementing-collectionchanged.html
Про mvvm простыми словами если вы используете события по типу Click  и т.п для работы с View частью это не нарушает mvvm. Но если у вас идет работа с бизнес логикой, то это нарушает паттерн, так как вы используете часть-которая должна быть вынесена в отдельный слой для этого.
